# R - GAM error - Missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, error-handling, gam, mgcv

I'm trying to train a binomial GAM model with the mgcv package, and running into this error:

`Error in if (length(grad) > 0 && sum(uconv.ind) > 0) { :  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`

There are no columns in my data frame (of the columns which are included in the model) that have NAs in them. When I look at the unique values of the response column, it shows `[1] 0 1` as expected.

Here is the code used to train the model:

`mgcv::bam(formula = formula, family = binomial, data = df, select = T, discrete = T, method = 'fREML', nthreads = 32, drop.unused.levels = FALSE)`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

As requested, here is a screenshot of a random sample of the data. The data is related to my company so I can't give too much information away:

[image]

The final column is the response, and it is a numeric column. When I type `df[!complete.cases(df), ]`, the result has 0 rows.

Comment: Can you provide some data for us? The error that you show us, indicates that there *are* missing values. And if you er certain that it is not from your data, then `class()` of you your variables are not compatible with `length()` and/or `sum()`. Please update your post accordingly.

Comment: Added a screenshot of the data. Let me know if that is helpful!

Comment: So, check this link please, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example